# Dealing with exceptions examples

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

May someone point me to an opensource project or a book or a site or any tips whatsoever for "good practices" in dealing with exception - e.g. retrying the offending code or any other accepted strategy.

Comment: No idea about books (though for C++ you could try "Exceptional C++" by Herb Sutter, I imagine the ideas are essentially the same); here are two previous answers of mine on the subject: [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589489/how-to-avoid-many-try-catch-blocks-in-java/6589526#6589526), [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372732/exception-catching-when-not-to-catch-them/7372866#7372866).

Answer (score 3):

- [Exception Antipatterns](http://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns)
- [10 best practices](http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/10_best_practices_with_Exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

There's an entire chapter in Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) dedicated to effective use of exceptions. This book comes highly recommended for any professional Java developer. I suggest that your purchase it (hehe..excuse the sales pitch).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Effective Java, there's [an entire book dealing with exception and error handling in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131008528).

Answer (score 0):

I liked this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/06/14/631923.aspx

It's about a code analysis tool which complains about catching general exceptions. But it also describes pretty well how exception handling should be done in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Bloch's Effective Java: Programming Language Guide (Addison-Wesley, 2001) has a chapter dedicated to exception handling.